# Using difftime() in C

Tags: c, visual-c++

I am using `difftime()` to try to subtract two dates. But consider, as in this example, I'm getting incorrect result. Here's the code:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <time.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <string.h>

const struct tm* stringToDate(const char *iDateStr)
{
    struct tm *tm = (struct tm*)malloc(sizeof(struct tm));
    memset(tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    sscanf_s(iDateStr, "%d-%d-%d", &tm->tm_mday, &tm->tm_mon, &tm->tm_year);
    tm->tm_year -= 1900;

    return tm;
}

const int stringDateDiffDays(const char *isDateTime1, const char *isDateTime2)
{
    const struct tm *d1 = stringToDate(isDateTime1);
    const struct tm *d2 = stringToDate(isDateTime2);

    int diff = 0;
    double diffSecs = 0;

    // Seconds since start of epoch
    diffSecs = difftime(mktime((struct tm*)d1), mktime((struct tm*)d2));

    free((void *)d1);
    free((void *)d2);

    diff = (int)(diffSecs/(3600*24));

    return diff;
}

int main(void)
{
    char date1[] = "16-11-2017";
    char date2[] = "16-12-2017";

    printf("Date 1: %10s\n", date1);
    printf("Date 2: %10s\n", date2);
    printf("\nDifference : %d", stringDateDiffDays(date2, date1));

    return 0;
}
```

What has happened? Is `stringToDate()` responsible for this, because of maybe the `memset()`? I am using `Visual Studio 2012` to compile this code. How could I correctly implement these functions?

Comment: what is the output?

Comment: It says 31, but it should be 30...

Comment: Can't compile this. I get `undefined reference to sscanf_s`

Comment: If you look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/, you'll see that tm_mon should be between 0 and 11, so try doing --tm->tm_mon.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem.

Comment: @klutt: sscanf_s() is a Microsoft extension. It might not be available with your compiler, so the linker error. To correct this you might have to replace it with some other portable variant.